# cygwin environment variables set in bat file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cygwin, environment

I need to set several environment variables that should be available in cygwin shell.

I tried running `"c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64"/vcvars64.bat` in ~/.bashrc. Script seems to run but it does not update environment variables.

How can I export variables set in bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends upon what you are trying to do. If you want access to those tools within Cygwin you can edit your `.bash_profile` and update your `PATH=` to match what `vcvars64.bat` has. This is how I get access to those tools.

You can also run `vcvars64.bat` before starting Cygwin by editing your `{cygwin dir}/Cygwin.bat` (assuming you're starting Cygwin via this file!) to run it before starting bash. This way the DOS environment would be set and Cygwin would pick it up.