# How to call a bat / cmd file from Cygwin and inherit the variables?

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd, cygwin

Suppose I have a `bat` (or `cmd`) script that sets an environment variable:

```
rem set_foo.bat
SET foo=XXX
```

I want to call that script from a Cygwin bash script, in such a way that the variable set by `set_foo.bat` is visible by the Cygwin bash script. That is, this Cygwin bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
<call set_foo.bat in such a way that FOO becomes visible to this Cygwin script>
echo FOO is ${FOO}
```

should print:

```
FOO is XXX
```

Is this possible, and how?

PS 1: I am aware of the solutions proposed here: [cygwin environment variables set in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430807/cygwin-environment-variables-set-in-bat-file), and they are NOT what I want.

PS 2: The bat script is not under my control (the Cygwin bash script is), so any solution that involves tweaking the bat script is not acceptable.

PS 3: If I just call `set_foo.bat` from the Cygwin bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set_foo.bat
echo FOO is ${FOO}
```

then the value of `FOO` is not visible. That is, the Cygwin bash script prints:

```
FOO is
```

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552812). You should define the variables in batch file needs `SET foo=XXX` to have a variable `%foo%` instead of `%foo %`. Please flag it yourself; no flags remaining for me :(.

Comment: See PS 2, which I just added to my original post.

Comment: Now, what are you getting?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the batch script, it's hard to say. If the script enables delayed expansion, you're out of luck, as that sandboxes the script's environment.

Comment: @dooble-beep See PS 3, which I just added.

Comment: @SomethingDark What if the bat script does not enable delayed expansion?

Comment: Then as long as you call both scripts using the same command prompt, you should have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export $(cmd /c "set_foo.bat & set foo" | grep "^foo=")
echo Foo is $foo
```

As long as `set_foo.bat` doesn't set the value of `%foo%` within a `setlocal` scope, the value should carry over to the `& set foo` half of the `cmd.exe`-interpreted command.  That will output the variable=value pair, which `export` will interpret as a native variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example. Make a `cygwin` shell script (with LF for EOL)

```
:
# runner.sh
cmd=/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe
$cmd /C wrapper.bat
diff env0.txt env1.txt | dos2unix | sed -e '/[0-9]/d' -e '/^> /s/> //'
```

and a cmd script (with CR/LF for EOL)

```
@rem wrapper.bat
@set > env0.txt
@call .\set_foo.bat
@set > env1.txt
```

and a stand-in for the original cmd file (also with CR/LF for EOL)

```
@rem set_foo.bat
@set FOO=BAZ
```

Executing `./runner.sh` from the shell will display environment variables set by the `set_foo.bat` cmd file. As long as that file does not use the `setlocal` command, you will see all environment changes in `wrapper.bat`. This should display new environment variables properly. Handling deletes or changes is left as an excercise for the reader, likewise passing in arguments.

HTH